# Recursion Javascript using JSON

Tags: javascript, json, recursion

My goal isn't to track the number of times the recursive call happens but rather the depth level in the JSON. I am trying to create a HTML table with the proper indentations using recursion. However I have no way of seeing what level I am at to determine where to properly "indent" a child element relative to its parent.

I have the following structure:

```
{
   "SMINFOREC":{
      "TSUTC":{
         "@attributes":{
            "hex":"404211D8",
            "intermediate":"1078071768",
            "uom":""
         },
         "#text":"2014-03-05T16:22:48Z"
      },
      "Trig":{
         "@attributes":{
            "hex":"0003",
            "intermediate":"3",
            "uom":""
         },
         "#text":"3"
      },
      "GID":{
         "@attributes":{
            "hex":"0C90",
            "intermediate":"3216",
            "uom":""
         },
         "DLID":{
            "#text":"12"
         },
         "MLID":{
            "#text":"144"
         }
      },
      "TOH":{
         "@attributes":{
            "hex":"0005540F",
            "intermediate":"349199",
            "uom":"hours"
         },
         "#text":"96.999799822"
      }
   }
}
```

I would like to recursively iterate this and also know the depth of the level I am currently processing I've been hacking at it for a good while now and not able to calculate the depth correctly any ideas?

edit*******

```
function iterate(obj,callback){
                      for (key in obj){
                       if(typeof obj[key] === 'object' && key !== "hex" && key !== "intermediate")
                        {
                           console.log("**********************************************");
                           console.log("key: " + key);
                           console.log("obj[key]: " + obj[key]);
                           console.log("level inside iterate callback: "  + level);
                           console.log("**********************************************");
                           iterate(obj[key],callback);

                        }
                       else if(key !="uom")
                       {
                           console.log("$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$");
                           console.log("key: " + key);
                           console.log("obj[key]: " + obj[key]);
                           console.log("$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$");
                           callback(obj[key]);
                       }

                      }
                      console.log("level: " + level);
                    }

                    iterate(jsonData[namespace].Data, function(obj){
                      level++;
                      console.log("---------------------------------------------");
                      console.log(obj);
                      console.log("level inside iterate: " + level);
                      console.log("---------------------------------------------");
                    });
```

Comment: `function recurse(foo, depth) { recurse(otherfoo, depth+1); }`, basically

Comment: What did you try that currently does not work?

Comment: see above. I've added to description. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm feeling generous...

```
var maxDepth = 0;
function traverse(node, depth) {
    maxDepth = Math.max(maxDepth, depth);
    //...do something with the data in the node if you want...
    //process children, if any
    for (var i in node) {
        traverse(node[i], depth+1);
    }
}

traverse(your-json);
```

Comment: I updated the code with more what I am tring to do. I've gone this route several times but I added some description to the above what I'm trying to accomplish thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can try following:

```
function iterate(obj,callback){
  for (key in obj){
   if(typeof obj[key] === 'object')
    iterate(obj[key],callback);
   else callback(obj[key]);
  }
}

iterate(jsn, function(obj){
  console.log(obj);
});
```

if you need to count the depth, have some variable increased every time you call iterate function.

Comment: I updated the code with more what I am tring to do. I've gone this route several times but I added some description to the above what I'm trying to accomplish thanks